how to make this horizontal menu start scroll from right to left?
you can see a full demo code for the menu here :
https://codepen.io/testkart/pen/OJBJZbp



document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
      const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
      const scrollLength = scrollImages.scrollWidth - scrollImages.clientWidth;
      const leftButton = document.querySelector(".left");
      const rightButton = document.querySelector(".right");

      function checkScroll() {
        const currentScroll = scrollImages.scrollLeft;
        if (currentScroll === 0) {
          leftButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
          rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        } else if (currentScroll === scrollLength) {
          rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
          leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        } else {
          leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
          rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }
      }

      scrollImages.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);
      window.addEventListener("resize", checkScroll);
      checkScroll();

      function leftScroll() {
        scrollImages.scrollBy({
          left: -200,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      }

      function rightScroll() {
        scrollImages.scrollBy({
          left: 200,
          behavior: "smooth"
        });
      }

      leftButton.addEventListener("click", leftScroll);
      rightButton.addEventListener("click", rightScroll);
    });
#left, #right {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.cover {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-images {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 1px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
}

.child img, .child > svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -195px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #03A9F4;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: black;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--
For more details-
https://www.testkarts.com/blog/horizontal-card-scroll-with-arrow -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a59b9b09ab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cover">
    <button class="left" onclick="leftScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="scroll-images">
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-1-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM9.283 4.002H7.971L6.072 5.385v1.271l1.834-1.318h.065V12h1.312V4.002Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-2-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM6.646 6.24c0-.691.493-1.306 1.336-1.306.756 0 1.313.492 1.313 1.236 0 .697-.469 1.23-.902 1.705l-2.971 3.293V12h5.344v-1.107H7.268v-.077l1.974-2.22.096-.107c.688-.763 1.287-1.428 1.287-2.43 0-1.266-1.031-2.215-2.613-2.215-1.758 0-2.637 1.19-2.637 2.402v.065h1.271v-.07Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-3-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.082.414c.92 0 1.535.54 1.541 1.318.012.791-.615 1.36-1.588 1.354-.861-.006-1.482-.469-1.54-1.066H5.104c.047 1.177 1.05 2.144 2.754 2.144 1.653 0 2.954-.937 2.93-2.396-.023-1.278-1.031-1.846-1.734-1.916v-.07c.597-.1 1.505-.739 1.482-1.876-.03-1.177-1.043-2.074-2.637-2.062-1.675.006-2.59.984-2.625 2.12h1.248c.036-.556.557-1.054 1.348-1.054.785 0 1.348.486 1.348 1.195.006.715-.563 1.237-1.342 1.237h-.838v1.072h.879Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-4-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM7.519 5.057c-.886 1.418-1.772 2.838-2.542 4.265v1.12H8.85V12h1.26v-1.559h1.007V9.334H10.11V4.002H8.176c-.218.352-.438.703-.657 1.055ZM6.225 9.281v.053H8.85V5.063h-.065c-.867 1.33-1.787 2.806-2.56 4.218Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-5-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.006 4.158c1.74 0 2.924-1.119 2.924-2.806 0-1.641-1.178-2.584-2.56-2.584-.897 0-1.442.421-1.612.68h-.064l.193-2.344h3.621V4.002H5.791L5.445 8.63h1.149c.193-.358.668-.809 1.435-.809.85 0 1.582.604 1.582 1.57 0 1.085-.779 1.682-1.57 1.682-.697 0-1.389-.31-1.53-1.031H5.276c.065 1.213 1.149 2.115 2.72 2.115Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 5</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-6-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM8.21 3.855c-1.868 0-3.116 1.395-3.116 4.407 0 1.183.228 2.039.597 2.642.569.926 1.477 1.254 2.409 1.254 1.629 0 2.847-1.013 2.847-2.783 0-1.676-1.254-2.555-2.508-2.555-1.125 0-1.752.61-1.98 1.155h-.082c-.012-1.946.727-3.036 1.805-3.036.802 0 1.213.457 1.312.815h1.29c-.06-.908-.962-1.899-2.573-1.899Zm-.099 4.008c-.92 0-1.564.65-1.564 1.576 0 1.032.703 1.635 1.558 1.635.868 0 1.553-.533 1.553-1.629 0-1.06-.744-1.582-1.547-1.582Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 6</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-7-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM5.37 5.11h3.972v.07L6.025 12H7.42l3.258-6.85V4.002H5.369v1.107Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 7</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-8-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-5.03 1.803c0-1.248-.943-1.84-1.646-1.992v-.065c.598-.187 1.336-.72 1.336-1.781 0-1.225-1.084-2.121-2.654-2.121-1.57 0-2.66.896-2.66 2.12 0 1.044.709 1.589 1.33 1.782v.065c-.697.152-1.647.732-1.647 2.003 0 1.39 1.19 2.344 2.953 2.344 1.77 0 2.989-.96 2.989-2.355Zm-4.347-3.71c0 .739.586 1.255 1.383 1.255s1.377-.516 1.377-1.254c0-.733-.58-1.23-1.377-1.23s-1.383.497-1.383 1.23Zm-.281 3.645c0 .838.72 1.412 1.664 1.412.943 0 1.658-.574 1.658-1.412 0-.843-.715-1.424-1.658-1.424-.944 0-1.664.58-1.664 1.424Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 8</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-9-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.223 4.146c2.104 0 3.123-1.464 3.123-4.3 0-3.147-1.459-4.014-2.97-4.014-1.63 0-2.871 1.02-2.871 2.73 0 1.706 1.171 2.667 2.566 2.667 1.06 0 1.7-.557 1.934-1.184h.076c.047 1.67-.475 3.023-1.834 3.023-.71 0-1.149-.363-1.248-.72H5.258c.094.908.926 1.798 2.52 1.798Zm.118-3.972c.808 0 1.535-.528 1.535-1.594s-.668-1.676-1.56-1.676c-.838 0-1.517.616-1.517 1.659 0 1.072.708 1.61 1.54 1.61Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 9</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="right" onclick="rightScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



when the site is LTR (left to right) the menu is working 100% good .
but in RTL direction it is not working good .
i think that this code force the menu scroll from the left :
if (currentScroll === 0)
how to force the menu to detect rtl or start scroll from right if the site is rtl direction ?

I've added an option to check if the page is in rtl or not.
function isRTL() {
  return document.documentElement.getAttribute("dir") === "rtl";
}

Demo


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  const leftButton = document.querySelector(".left");
  const rightButton = document.querySelector(".right");

  function isRTL() {
    return document.documentElement.getAttribute("dir") === "rtl";
  }

  function checkScroll() {
    const currentScroll = scrollImages.scrollLeft;
    const scrollLength = scrollImages.scrollWidth - scrollImages.clientWidth;

    if (isRTL()) {
      if (Math.abs(currentScroll) === 0) {
        rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else if (Math.abs(currentScroll) >= scrollLength) {
        leftButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    } else {
      if (currentScroll === 0) {
        leftButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else if (currentScroll >= scrollLength) {
        rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    }
  }

  scrollImages.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);
  window.addEventListener("resize", checkScroll);
  checkScroll();

  leftButton.addEventListener("click", leftScroll);
  rightButton.addEventListener("click", rightScroll);
});

// Move the scroll functions outside the DOMContentLoaded listener
function leftScroll() {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  scrollImages.scrollBy({
    left: -200,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

function rightScroll() {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  scrollImages.scrollBy({
    left: 200,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

function isRTL() {
  return document.documentElement.getAttribute("dir") === "rtl";
}
/*
For more details-
https://www.testkarts.com/blog/horizontal-card-scroll-with-arrow */
.cover {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-images {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 1px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
}

.child img, .child > svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -195px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #03A9F4;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: black;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!--
For more details-
https://www.testkarts.com/blog/horizontal-card-scroll-with-arrow -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a59b9b09ab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cover">
    <button class="left" onclick="leftScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="scroll-images">
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-1-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM9.283 4.002H7.971L6.072 5.385v1.271l1.834-1.318h.065V12h1.312V4.002Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-2-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM6.646 6.24c0-.691.493-1.306 1.336-1.306.756 0 1.313.492 1.313 1.236 0 .697-.469 1.23-.902 1.705l-2.971 3.293V12h5.344v-1.107H7.268v-.077l1.974-2.22.096-.107c.688-.763 1.287-1.428 1.287-2.43 0-1.266-1.031-2.215-2.613-2.215-1.758 0-2.637 1.19-2.637 2.402v.065h1.271v-.07Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-3-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.082.414c.92 0 1.535.54 1.541 1.318.012.791-.615 1.36-1.588 1.354-.861-.006-1.482-.469-1.54-1.066H5.104c.047 1.177 1.05 2.144 2.754 2.144 1.653 0 2.954-.937 2.93-2.396-.023-1.278-1.031-1.846-1.734-1.916v-.07c.597-.1 1.505-.739 1.482-1.876-.03-1.177-1.043-2.074-2.637-2.062-1.675.006-2.59.984-2.625 2.12h1.248c.036-.556.557-1.054 1.348-1.054.785 0 1.348.486 1.348 1.195.006.715-.563 1.237-1.342 1.237h-.838v1.072h.879Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-4-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM7.519 5.057c-.886 1.418-1.772 2.838-2.542 4.265v1.12H8.85V12h1.26v-1.559h1.007V9.334H10.11V4.002H8.176c-.218.352-.438.703-.657 1.055ZM6.225 9.281v.053H8.85V5.063h-.065c-.867 1.33-1.787 2.806-2.56 4.218Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-5-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.006 4.158c1.74 0 2.924-1.119 2.924-2.806 0-1.641-1.178-2.584-2.56-2.584-.897 0-1.442.421-1.612.68h-.064l.193-2.344h3.621V4.002H5.791L5.445 8.63h1.149c.193-.358.668-.809 1.435-.809.85 0 1.582.604 1.582 1.57 0 1.085-.779 1.682-1.57 1.682-.697 0-1.389-.31-1.53-1.031H5.276c.065 1.213 1.149 2.115 2.72 2.115Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 5</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-6-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM8.21 3.855c-1.868 0-3.116 1.395-3.116 4.407 0 1.183.228 2.039.597 2.642.569.926 1.477 1.254 2.409 1.254 1.629 0 2.847-1.013 2.847-2.783 0-1.676-1.254-2.555-2.508-2.555-1.125 0-1.752.61-1.98 1.155h-.082c-.012-1.946.727-3.036 1.805-3.036.802 0 1.213.457 1.312.815h1.29c-.06-.908-.962-1.899-2.573-1.899Zm-.099 4.008c-.92 0-1.564.65-1.564 1.576 0 1.032.703 1.635 1.558 1.635.868 0 1.553-.533 1.553-1.629 0-1.06-.744-1.582-1.547-1.582Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 6</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-7-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM5.37 5.11h3.972v.07L6.025 12H7.42l3.258-6.85V4.002H5.369v1.107Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 7</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-8-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-5.03 1.803c0-1.248-.943-1.84-1.646-1.992v-.065c.598-.187 1.336-.72 1.336-1.781 0-1.225-1.084-2.121-2.654-2.121-1.57 0-2.66.896-2.66 2.12 0 1.044.709 1.589 1.33 1.782v.065c-.697.152-1.647.732-1.647 2.003 0 1.39 1.19 2.344 2.953 2.344 1.77 0 2.989-.96 2.989-2.355Zm-4.347-3.71c0 .739.586 1.255 1.383 1.255s1.377-.516 1.377-1.254c0-.733-.58-1.23-1.377-1.23s-1.383.497-1.383 1.23Zm-.281 3.645c0 .838.72 1.412 1.664 1.412.943 0 1.658-.574 1.658-1.412 0-.843-.715-1.424-1.658-1.424-.944 0-1.664.58-1.664 1.424Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 8</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-9-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.223 4.146c2.104 0 3.123-1.464 3.123-4.3 0-3.147-1.459-4.014-2.97-4.014-1.63 0-2.871 1.02-2.871 2.73 0 1.706 1.171 2.667 2.566 2.667 1.06 0 1.7-.557 1.934-1.184h.076c.047 1.67-.475 3.023-1.834 3.023-.71 0-1.149-.363-1.248-.72H5.258c.094.908.926 1.798 2.52 1.798Zm.118-3.972c.808 0 1.535-.528 1.535-1.594s-.668-1.676-1.56-1.676c-.838 0-1.517.616-1.517 1.659 0 1.072.708 1.61 1.54 1.61Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 9</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="right" onclick="rightScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Demo with RTL


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  const leftButton = document.querySelector(".left");
  const rightButton = document.querySelector(".right");

  function isRTL() {
    return document.documentElement.getAttribute("dir") === "rtl";
  }

  function checkScroll() {
    const currentScroll = scrollImages.scrollLeft;
    const scrollLength = scrollImages.scrollWidth - scrollImages.clientWidth;

    if (isRTL()) {
      if (Math.abs(currentScroll) === 0) {
        rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else if (Math.abs(currentScroll) >= scrollLength) {
        leftButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    } else {
      if (currentScroll === 0) {
        leftButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else if (currentScroll >= scrollLength) {
        rightButton.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      } else {
        leftButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        rightButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }
    }
  }

  scrollImages.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);
  window.addEventListener("resize", checkScroll);
  checkScroll();

  leftButton.addEventListener("click", leftScroll);
  rightButton.addEventListener("click", rightScroll);
});

// Move the scroll functions outside the DOMContentLoaded listener
function leftScroll() {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  scrollImages.scrollBy({
    left: -200,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

function rightScroll() {
  const scrollImages = document.querySelector(".scroll-images");
  scrollImages.scrollBy({
    left: 200,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}

function isRTL() {
  return document.documentElement.getAttribute("dir") === "rtl";
}
/*
For more details-
https://www.testkarts.com/blog/horizontal-card-scroll-with-arrow */
.cover {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.scroll-images {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0px;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.child {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 0px 15px;
    margin: 1px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 10%);;
}

.child img, .child > svg {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -195px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #03A9F4;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}

.scroll-images::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: black;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">
<!--
For more details-
https://www.testkarts.com/blog/horizontal-card-scroll-with-arrow -->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a59b9b09ab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cover">
    <button class="left" onclick="leftScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-left"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="scroll-images">
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-1-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM9.283 4.002H7.971L6.072 5.385v1.271l1.834-1.318h.065V12h1.312V4.002Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 1</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-2-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM6.646 6.24c0-.691.493-1.306 1.336-1.306.756 0 1.313.492 1.313 1.236 0 .697-.469 1.23-.902 1.705l-2.971 3.293V12h5.344v-1.107H7.268v-.077l1.974-2.22.096-.107c.688-.763 1.287-1.428 1.287-2.43 0-1.266-1.031-2.215-2.613-2.215-1.758 0-2.637 1.19-2.637 2.402v.065h1.271v-.07Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 2</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-3-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.082.414c.92 0 1.535.54 1.541 1.318.012.791-.615 1.36-1.588 1.354-.861-.006-1.482-.469-1.54-1.066H5.104c.047 1.177 1.05 2.144 2.754 2.144 1.653 0 2.954-.937 2.93-2.396-.023-1.278-1.031-1.846-1.734-1.916v-.07c.597-.1 1.505-.739 1.482-1.876-.03-1.177-1.043-2.074-2.637-2.062-1.675.006-2.59.984-2.625 2.12h1.248c.036-.556.557-1.054 1.348-1.054.785 0 1.348.486 1.348 1.195.006.715-.563 1.237-1.342 1.237h-.838v1.072h.879Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 3</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-4-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM7.519 5.057c-.886 1.418-1.772 2.838-2.542 4.265v1.12H8.85V12h1.26v-1.559h1.007V9.334H10.11V4.002H8.176c-.218.352-.438.703-.657 1.055ZM6.225 9.281v.053H8.85V5.063h-.065c-.867 1.33-1.787 2.806-2.56 4.218Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 4</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-5-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.006 4.158c1.74 0 2.924-1.119 2.924-2.806 0-1.641-1.178-2.584-2.56-2.584-.897 0-1.442.421-1.612.68h-.064l.193-2.344h3.621V4.002H5.791L5.445 8.63h1.149c.193-.358.668-.809 1.435-.809.85 0 1.582.604 1.582 1.57 0 1.085-.779 1.682-1.57 1.682-.697 0-1.389-.31-1.53-1.031H5.276c.065 1.213 1.149 2.115 2.72 2.115Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 5</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-6-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM8.21 3.855c-1.868 0-3.116 1.395-3.116 4.407 0 1.183.228 2.039.597 2.642.569.926 1.477 1.254 2.409 1.254 1.629 0 2.847-1.013 2.847-2.783 0-1.676-1.254-2.555-2.508-2.555-1.125 0-1.752.61-1.98 1.155h-.082c-.012-1.946.727-3.036 1.805-3.036.802 0 1.213.457 1.312.815h1.29c-.06-.908-.962-1.899-2.573-1.899Zm-.099 4.008c-.92 0-1.564.65-1.564 1.576 0 1.032.703 1.635 1.558 1.635.868 0 1.553-.533 1.553-1.629 0-1.06-.744-1.582-1.547-1.582Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 6</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-7-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0ZM5.37 5.11h3.972v.07L6.025 12H7.42l3.258-6.85V4.002H5.369v1.107Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 7</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-8-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-5.03 1.803c0-1.248-.943-1.84-1.646-1.992v-.065c.598-.187 1.336-.72 1.336-1.781 0-1.225-1.084-2.121-2.654-2.121-1.57 0-2.66.896-2.66 2.12 0 1.044.709 1.589 1.33 1.782v.065c-.697.152-1.647.732-1.647 2.003 0 1.39 1.19 2.344 2.953 2.344 1.77 0 2.989-.96 2.989-2.355Zm-4.347-3.71c0 .739.586 1.255 1.383 1.255s1.377-.516 1.377-1.254c0-.733-.58-1.23-1.377-1.23s-1.383.497-1.383 1.23Zm-.281 3.645c0 .838.72 1.412 1.664 1.412.943 0 1.658-.574 1.658-1.412 0-.843-.715-1.424-1.658-1.424-.944 0-1.664.58-1.664 1.424Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 8</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="child">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-9-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
          <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0Zm-8.223 4.146c2.104 0 3.123-1.464 3.123-4.3 0-3.147-1.459-4.014-2.97-4.014-1.63 0-2.871 1.02-2.871 2.73 0 1.706 1.171 2.667 2.566 2.667 1.06 0 1.7-.557 1.934-1.184h.076c.047 1.67-.475 3.023-1.834 3.023-.71 0-1.149-.363-1.248-.72H5.258c.094.908.926 1.798 2.52 1.798Zm.118-3.972c.808 0 1.535-.528 1.535-1.594s-.668-1.676-1.56-1.676c-.838 0-1.517.616-1.517 1.659 0 1.072.708 1.61 1.54 1.61Z"/>
        </svg>
        <h4>Card 9</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="right" onclick="rightScroll()">
      <i class="fas fa-angle-double-right"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



